# How to sort list with dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting

I have list:

```
[
    {'name': 'peter', 'age': 41, 'value': 1},
    {'name': 'jon', 'age': 31, 'value': 5},
    {'name': 'alan', 'age': 23, 'value': 3}
]
```

How to sort this list by 'age'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lambda function and one of the following functions to sort:

If you want to sort in-place (modify the list):

```
L.sort(key = lambda d:d['age'])
```

If you want to create a new sorted list:

```
print sorted(L, key = lambda d:d['age'])
```